# How to convert one column to date format in awk script?

Tags: bash, date, awk

```
cat test.txt | 
 awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" } ;{ print  $44=strftime("%d %b %Y",$44)  "\t" $44 }'
```

I have received:

```
 31 12 1969      2012-09-27
```

But I have expected:

```
 27 Sep 2012      2012-09-27
```

Where is the error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you really want to convert the format with awk build-in functions, this example may help you:

```
kent$  echo "2012-09-27" |awk '{t=$0;gsub("-"," ",t);print strftime("%d %b %Y", mktime(t" 00 00 00"))}' 
27 Sep 2012
```

read the description of following functions in man page:

```
 mktime(datespec)
 strftime([format [, timestamp[, utc-flag]]])
```

**edit** try to fix you old command, but no input file, cannot test it...

```
 awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}{t=$44;gsub("-"," ",t); print strftime("%d %b %Y", mktime(t" 00 00 00")),$44}' test.txt
```

Comment: I have asked about error, but you send me new script. Do you think that for me more easy investigate 2 scripts than 1?

Comment: GAWK has a special function for creating strings based on the current time. It's based on the strftime(3c) function. I don't need current time.

Comment: @user710818 did you check that line in my answer? it is not new. it is exactly what you did wrong. if you want the complete line, ok, I make if for you...

Comment: So you have only suggested a way to resolve the problem. I think that it is wrong. In bash/awk evil in details - when you try to make exactly.

Comment: @user710818 and i didn't use `currenttime` at all... you should read the answer. buddy...